# Oracle and SQL Server select (+) equivalent

Tags: sql-server, oracle, select, outer-join

In Oracle I have:

```
SELECT t2.Regkood, t2.naitatel, t2.naitafaks, t3.lahtiolekuaeg, t1.*
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
WHERE t1.client = t2.client AND t1.client = t3.client(+) AND t1.client = 414246
```

How do I get the same in SQL Server?

thanks

Comment: :Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN ` syntax

Comment: You should not use `(+)` in Oracle. Use standard `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.Regkood, 
       t2.naitatel, 
       t2.naitafaks, 
       t3.lahtiolekuaeg, 
       t1.* 
FROM   table1 t1 
       INNER JOIN table2 t2 
               ON t1.client = t2.client 
       LEFT JOIN table3 t3 
               ON t1.client = t3.client 
WHERE  t1.client = 414246
```

Some samples to understand joins:

LEFT OUTER JOIN in ORACLE

```
SELECT *
FROM A, B
WHERE A.column = B.column(+)
```

RIGHT OUTER JOIN IN ORACLE

```
SELECT *
FROM A, B
WHERE A.column(+)=B.column
```

Comment: @Romil : Just out of  interest can you please explain me what does + symbol stands for in Oracle ?

Comment: In previous version of oracle (we use +) and sql server (we use *) to denote left or right join.

Comment: Your two Oracle joins are equivalent (`A LEFT JOIN B`). If instead you want to write `A RIGHT JOIN B` you would write something like this: `SELECT * FROM A,B WHERE A.column (+) = B.column`

Comment: I am afraid I don't see such thing on my page :|

Answer (score 0):

Actually to me the question looks like a concatenate question which in Oracle is used as two pipes side by side:

Oracle: select FirstName||' '||LastName
Returns: John Doe (if FirstName = John and LastName = Doe)

is the same as

MSSQL: select FirstName+' '+LastName
Returns: John Doe (if FirstName = John and LastName = Doe)